# Ruby on Rails application/REST API authentication architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, architecture

I'm going to develop a Ruby on Rails application (basically a back-office) which at the same time will serve data for an Android mobile app via the REST interface Rails provides.
My concerns here are the following: how should I manage and structure my ROR application so that REST calls from Android are authenticated with an API Key + user ID (I was also thinking in using OAuth) and, on the other side, users can interact with via back-office.
Should I use for example different controllers for the same resources (thus, increasing complexity) for BO accesses and Mobile client accesses (so I can implement different auth logic)?
Is there any standard/common way (aka gem) to manage and implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, I create dedicated controllers, I like things to be split. Moreover it lets you have api controllers inheriting from a root ApiController with it's own auth rules

Comment: Hi apneadiving, thanks for replying. So you suggest having controllers dedicated to Mobile client API calls? However this brings me another question: then, how can I prevent "BO controllers" from being called outside the back-office context?

Comment: As i wrote, I have a dedicated auth system for my api, so I redirect everything else

Comment: I get it now. As API controllers will respond with json/xml/whatever and BO controllers limited to the HTML part, it will suit my needs - prevent 'useful' data access (i.e. json/xml) via non-API controllers.